# How to check if a phone is rooted from a PC

Tags: rooting, unrooting

I am trying to find a fast way to see if an android phone is rooted or not. I know you can use root checker app but due to numbers of phones it is far too slow to install and use.

I am looking for a way that I use. I know I have to turn ADB on, on the phone and plug it into my pc.

Is there a way to check this using command a line I can run in CMD?

I have android studio install so is there a way of running a script from this that will check to see if a phone has been rooted?

I know what due to number of way a phone can be rooted it not always 100% but I can live with that.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `adb shell` command to check if the phone is rooted. Execute `adb shell su` and if the phone is rooted a root shell will be opened. If it's not rooted you will get a `su: not found` error message.

Comment: Don't forget to install ADB environment on the computer first and have drivers installed :)

Comment: Yeah that would be useful... :)